# Ionic 3 tab icon I want to change the background image at touch start, touch end

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to change 'tab icon' when `touchstart` or `touchend` event occurs.

```
onTouchStart(e) {
    if (e.target.attributes['aria-label'] && e.target.attributes['aria-label'].value == 'home') {
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/imgs/homeRoot.png)";
    }
  }

  onTouchEnd(e) {
    if (e.target.attributes['aria-label'] && e.target.attributes['aria-label'].value == 'home') {
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/imgs/homeRoot_default.png)";
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-tabs (touchstart)="onTouchStart($event);" (touchend)="onTouchEnd($event);">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="One" tabIcon="one"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Two" tabIcon="Tow"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Three" tabIcon="Three"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Four" tabIcon="Four"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I want to show you which tab you are touching when the touch starts.
In 'ionic tabs', there is no processing for touch start, so I implemented it directly as above.
But It does not work on Android.

Touch Before:

[image]

Touch End:

[image]

`backgroundImage` disappears and is not in its original state.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: ok. I have modified the description in detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export xyz{
tabs = [{root: "tab1Root",menu: "1st menu", icon: "iconname"},{root: "tab2Root", menu: "2nd menu", icon: "iconname},{root: "tab3Root",menu: "3rd menu", icon: "iconname}];
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs (touchstart)="foo($event);" (touchend)="bar($event);">
<span *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
  <ion-tab [root]="tab.root" tabTitle="tab.menu" tabIcon="tab.icon"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```